# Можно ли в Django добавить нестандартный язык?

Tags: django, locale

На данный момент в **settings.py** определено:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', 'Русский'),
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('ady', 'Адыгабзэ'),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'),)
)
```

Русский и английские языки работают нормально, но адыгейский нет. На википедии нашел, что адыгейский язык имеет код *ady*, но в на [странице на которую ссылается документация](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html) этого языка нет, да к тому же все коды имеют двухзначный код.

Пробовал в папке *locale* создать директорию *ady* и затем выполнить команды

```
django-admin makemessages --all
django-admin compilemessages
```

Затем открывал сайт и появлялась ошибка *Unknown language code ady*

Подскажите, можно ли добавить адыгейский язык в проект, чтобы он работал?

Comment: Предложенное тут пробовали? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946830/how-to-add-new-languages-into-django-my-language-uyghur-or-uighur-is-not-su

Comment: @Eleferen, да, пробовал. В конце пользователь potemkin написал ответ, что появляется ошибка. У меня тоже самое.

Comment: @SimpleUser разобраться в сути возникающей ошибки не пробовали?

Comment: @andreymal, пробовал, конечно, но не понимаю. Т.к. мало разбирался в самом языке Python

Comment: @SimpleUser в таком случае вам (и potemkin'у тоже) следовало бы предварительно почитать учебники по Python, прежде чем работать с Django. `LANG_INFO = dict(list(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO.items()) + list(EXTRA_LANG_INFO.items()))`

Comment: @andreymal, Вы правы) Спасибо. Получилось сделать. К тому же, в последней строке должен быть список, не кортеж, т.е. `... + ['ady']`, а не `... + ('ady',)`. Добавьте это в ответ, отмечу как решенный вопрос

Comment: @SimpleUser странно, у меня самого не получается добавить язык из-за ошибки No translation files found for default language, так что ответа пока не будет) Какая у вас версия Django?

Comment: @andreymal, но я уже реализовал и перевод отображается на сайте. Использую 2.1. Может Вы компиляцию упустили или перезапуск сервера?

Comment: @SimpleUser разобрался, нельзя ставить `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ady'`, тогда и возникает эта ошибка

Comment: @andreymal, LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'. Оставил его, т.к. если перевод не был найден, то отображалось на русском.

Comment: @andreymal, не знаю почему, но у меня не отображается ошибка, даже если `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ady'`. Перезапускаю сервер и он все равное по умолчанию в адресной строке пишет `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/`.

Comment: @SimpleUser потому что вы уже заранее успели создать mo-файлы. Если их удалить (как будто они никогда и не создавались), то ошибка появится. Я распишу это подробнее в ответе

Comment: но при этом на разные языки сайт переводится

Comment: @andreymal, так и есть. Заметил, что `gettext_noop = labda s: s` и последняя строка `LANGUAGES_BIDI = ...` нет необходимости писать. `LANGUAGES_BIDI` используется для языков, которые читаются справа-налево

Comment: @SimpleUser gettext_noop есть, тоже распишу в ответе

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946830/how-to-add-new-languages-into-django-my-language-uyghur-or-uighur-is-not-su

Comment: Новые вопросы должны задаваться отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для неизвестных джанге языков придётся слегка пропатчить саму джангу.

Добавьте в ваш файл настроек (**settings.py**):

```
from django.conf import global_settings

# Это нужно, чтобы название самого языка можно было перевести на разные языки
gettext_noop = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
       ('ady', gettext_noop('Adyghe')),
)

EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'ady': {
        # Здесь ставим True для языков с написанием справа налево
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'ady',
        'name': 'Adyghe',
        'name_local': 'Адыгабзэ',
    },
}

import django.conf.locale
LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO, **EXTRA_LANG_INFO)
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO

# Обновление списка языков с написанием справа налево.
# Для адыгейского языка это не требуется, но для других может пригодиться
# LANGUAGES_BIDI = global_settings.LANGUAGES_BIDI + ["ady"]
```

После этого создаём файлы с переводами:

```
./manage.py makemessages -l ady
./manage.py compilemessages
```

Нюанс: нельзя ставить `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ady'`, здесь обязательно должен быть прописан один из стантартных языков Django. Дело в том, что Django хочет найти хотя бы один mo-файл для языка по умолчанию, а если не находит, то выдаёт ошибку «No translation files found for default language». (После `compilemessages` mo-файлы появятся и ставить `LANGUAGE_CODE` в принципе можно, но я бы всё равно на всякий случай не рекомендовал это делать.)

Благодаря заглушке `gettext_noop` в файлах `django.po` появится строчка с названием языка, позволяющая перевести его на другие языки, например на русский (`your_django_app/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`):

```
#: your_django_app/settings.py:777
msgid "Adyghe"
msgstr "Адыгейский"
```

Comment: Круто и подробно расписано. Спасибо. Забыл зачем нужен был `gettext_noop`, т.к. для данного примера использовал _gettext_lazy_ `from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy`

Comment: появилась новая проблема: выложит сайт на pythonanywhere.com, настроил его, сайт полностью работает и можно переключаться как на русский, так и на английский языки, но когда переключаюсь на адыгейский, то появляется ошибка `invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION`. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: @SimpleUser а без pythonanywhere ошибки нет, что ли?

Comment: на локальном сервере ошибки не возникает и перевод тоже работает, при этом файл `.po` содержит только 70 сообщений для перевода (все сообщения для сайта), но на сервере он разрастается до 300 сообщений. При нажатии на смену языка (на сервере) появляется эта ошибка. В вопрос добавлю логи

Comment: Забыл сказать, что при переключении языка на сайте, например, на английский в админке тоже все переводилось на английский. Может с этим как-то связано

Comment: .po и .mo файлы локальные и на сервере не должны различаться вообще никак, так что вы явно что-то делаете не так. Но в любом случае, очевидно, ищите ошибку в одном из этих 300 сообщений

Comment: @SimpleUser Или даже не в сообщениях, а в этом самом plural-forms. В любмо случае это точно не имеет отношения к подключению нового языка в Django, следовательно должен быть задан отдельный вопрос с содержимым файла django.po

Comment: хотел чтобы полностью готовый ответ был в одном вопросе, но подумывал задать новый. Немного позже посмотрим, пока попробую разобраться

Comment: @SimpleUser этот ответ полностью готовый, а у вас совсем другая проблема сейчас, которая могла случиться и без адыгейского

Comment: кстати да, это совсем к другому относится. Спасибо за замечание

Comment: сейчас заметил, что в файле `django.po` адыгейского языка немного различается структура: `"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"`. Вот откуда появляется эта ошибка, т.к. в том же файле английского языка прописано: `"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"`

Comment: Разобрался, в чем была проблема. Когда размещал сайт на сервере, то в папке с проектом создал папку с виртуальным окружением и при выполнении команд `makemessages` и `compilemessages` в файлы `.po` добавлялись лишние данные из виртуального окружения и также добавлялась строка `Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;`. В интернете находил, что эту строку можно было удалить или заменить значениями и тогда будет работать, но при попытке это сделать ничего не происходило (видимо перекрывались другими файлами из вирт. окружения). В итоге вирт. окружение вынес за проект и все заработало.